# Python: Extract a substring given a word and an interval

Tags: python

Given a text, a word and an interval, return the substring that contains the word within the range in the most efficient way. The idea is that when making a query return the context where the words ocurr, something similar to what Google does.

For example:

```
text = "This is an example of a string"
word = "example"
interval = 2
```

return:

```python
"is an example of a"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Could you explain the relation between the size of the interval and the expected output? Do you want the target word +- [interval]-words on each side as substring?

Comment: The interval is the number of words closest to the word that I want to return, and return only that substring: [interval] + word + [interval]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure is it the best solution of your problem, but..

```
outer_pattern = ''
for i in range(interval):
  outer_pattern += '\w+ '

pattern = '{}{} {}'.format(outer_pattern, word, outer_pattern)
result = [text[match.start():match.end()] for match in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
```

result here is the list of all matches

Comment: thanks for your reply. How could you modify the regular expression so that when there is a smaller number of elements that in the interval also recognize it? For example if the word is in one of the ends of the string I would like it to return that interval too.